Paralleling EMC filter
I have the following architecture:

This is the first time I see an architecture like this. I am more familiar with this king of architecture:

I would like to have your opinion on this subject. The first one with the 2 EMC filters seems to be better for reducing the input noise (ripple voltage and ripple current) on the sensitive load as there is an EMC filter which allows to separate the sensitive load from the noisy load. This architecture will probably take more surface on the board as there is 2 EMC filter.
The second one has the advantages of having only one filter but the sensitive load is not "protected" from the noisy load as it share the same "power supply".
Do you think that I could have a some kind of resonance between EMC filter which could affect the EMC results? If you have any advices do not hesitate!
Thank you,

I doesn't really make sense to speak of this on some big picture schematic level. "EMC filter" could be anything. The rule of thumb is to filter as close to the noise source as possible and that's about it. Also a "filter" (common mode/differential etc) is not necessarily the only EMI counter: TVS and/or freewheel diodes are also often necessary. There's also the desperate "EMC test failed smack on some ferrites on various cables and pray" filters, which may not come with much in the way of a rationale :)

In general when trying to isolate something that makes noise and something that is sensitive to noise, placement can be very important and it's something that doesn't even exist in a block diagram. So it is hard to say. Generally, filter the noisy load as much as necessary to comply with EMC. Then, add more DM/CM power supply smoothing to your sensitive stuff as needed.

Thnak you for your comment. I will do what you recommend me to do !
